When refrence frame has the same velocity of electron the we observe that electron seems like satatic. Then why it produces megnetic field. And why it
When refrence frame has the same velocity of electron the we observe that electron seems like satatic. Then why it produces megnetic field.

Why do you think a stationary electron produces a magnetic field (in is own frame)?

I am talking about moving electron in moving frame

A charge creates a magnetic field in any frame where it is moving.   It's very hard to tell what you're asking.

You might wan to look up electromagnetic Lorentz transformations.

Hi Pankaj and welcome to the Physics SE. It's a great question, but it has been asked before. Have a look at How do moving charges produce magnetic fields?.

electrons have a magnetic moment and a charge. Since $\vec E \cdot \vec B$ and $E^2-B^2$ are Lorentz invariants, there is no frame there is no magnetic field.

Is magnetism an intrinsic property of matter like electric charge
The electron is the origin of two fields. Both fields - the magnetic and the electric - have constant field strengths:
• The elementary magnetic dipole is a constant (https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?muem).
• In an unbounded state, the electric elementary charge is a constant (https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?e).
Conclusion: Electrons are in unity both magnetic dipoles and electric elementary charges.
